# Why are these dark patches on Cycles render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Why are there dark patches on top of the tyres when i render in cycles?
They are not there in EEVEE or the shading section.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like double geometry. Some object might be hidden for viewport, but visible for render. Check objects in the Outliner:

[image]

Here Suzanne is hidden for the viewport(eye icon), disabled globally in all viewports(screen icon), but visible for render(camera icon).

Make sure Outliner displays all of the wways to hide objects here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, i checked that and all are visible on viewport.

Comment: Could you share the .blend file with the problematic object in it? You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ for that.